node_modules error TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
I just randomly got this error when i deployed my application using AWS Amplify
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@fullcalendar/daygrid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
it just gives me that error and ive looked online for hours and theres no fix i tried everything, reinstalled the modules etc. Im using Vite to run npm build and then im using the dist folder to upload to AWS. all the files are there in the node_modules in my S3 bucket i have them as well its all there. but no matter what i try i keep getting that error
in my application im importing them like this:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import multiMonthPlugin from '@fullcalendar/multimonth';
import axios from 'axios';

In my localhost is works absolutely fine i have no issues so i'm assuming it has something to do with deployment
my vite.config
import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src',  // Custom alias for your src folder

    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json']

  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      'chunk-LG6VQEW3',
      'chunk-OLITY7PF',
      'chunk-3WLOWADN'
    ]
  },

  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        "@fullcalendar/core",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid",
      ],
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
          }
          if (id.includes('@fullcalendar')) {
            console.log('Resolving FullCalendar module:', id);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

});

File structure:
project
-app
-src <--- where my component is located
-node_modules
-dist
-index.html
-vite.config.js
if im guessing it for some reason when uploading its thinking its an alias when it should be a scope module and its trying to path to a folder called fullcalendar which does exist.
